# asynctask executed in onResume after onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Some specific situation:

I have two `Activities`. `FirstActivity` loads data from network(~100 kb) and is able to launch `SecondActivity` through `startActivityForResult()`. After getting result another network call should be triggered. All that works fine, except the performance. Here is the problem.

I trigger `AsyncTask` from `onActivityResult()`, or `onResume()` or `onPostResume()`. I expect that `SecondActivity` finishes, `FirstActivity` gets shown and the `ProgressBar` displayed, indicating my downloading works. But instead I see the following:

`SecondActivity` freezes, the `FirstActivity` gets launched(i see it in logs), `AsyncTask` triggered and `FirstActivity` gets shown only when `AsyncTask` finished it's work!

It is also strange, because I use exactly the same code when firstly start `FirstActivity` and all works as expected.

So, the question:

What is the difference between launching `AsyncTask` from `onCreate()` and `onActivityResult()`? Why android behaves like that? Is it version specific?

Thanks a lot.

Some code:

Activity A(first):

```
void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setupUI();
    code = 1;
    launchLoading(code);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    launchLoading(resultCode);
}
```

Activity B(second):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            setResult(i);
            finish();
        }
 });
```

**UPD**:

I create a list of custom views(~ 50) in onPostExecute() method. Why it is causing troubles?

Comment: provide the code of your AsyncTask class - your problem is likely caused by the wrong implementation of `onPostExecute(..)` method

Comment: Thanks for the point. I found one line in onPostExecute() method causing problems. I'm going to investigate for a while. I will update the question with the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all. The problem has been found in other place. In `FirstActivity` I have a list of custom views. Each one holds a small bitmap, but the count of these views are close to 50. So, when you return to the `FirstActivity`, `onMeasure()` is called for each of that view. It is performance important to do this as fast as possible. When I improved this method the problem has gone.

Answer (score 0):

when you return back from another activity it just resume activity it dont go in onCreate method(). what you need to do is start another activity from your asyntask activity using **startActivityForResult()** and override **onActivityResult** method in your asyntask activity. and in onActivityResult() execute the asyntask again. Better you do this in place of calling from asyntask in Onresume because in some other case also it will go in Onresume like pressing home key and going again

Answer (score 0):

Both, `onPostExecute(..)` and `onPreExecute(..)` methods are executed in UI-thread (which may cause freezes), while `doInBackground(..)` being executed in a separate thread. Consider moving time-consuming operations from `onPostExecute(..)` to `doInBackground(..)` method.

Anyway, it's hard to advice you anything without seeing your AsyncTask class and launchLoading(resultCode) method code.